# need help creating a static c++ library using make

Tags: c++, makefile, g++

I am trying to create a static library based on the file layout given below.

```
/library
    Makefile
    /include
        .h files
    /src
        .cpp files
    /build
        .o files
    /lib
        .a file
```

When I run make all with the current code in my makefile given below it gives me the error:

make: *** No rule to make target `src/%.cpp', needed by`build/BaseGfxApp.o'.  Stop.

```
    CPP_FILES = $(wildcard src/*.cpp)
    OBJ_FILES = $(addprefix build/,$(notdir $(CPP_FILES:.cpp=.o)))
    CC_FLAGS = -c -Wall

    all: libphoto.a

    libphoto.a: $(OBJ_FILES)
        ar rcs lib/$@ $^

    build/%.o: src/%.cpp
       g++ $(CC_FLAGS) $@ $<
```

I am fairly new to 'make' and I honestly have no clue where to go from here. I would appreciate some input or help. Thanks!

Comment: That `Makefile` expects the `src/` directory to be underneath the `library/` directory. The path is relative. Maybe move the `Makefile` out of the `library/` directory?

Comment: yea woops i messed up the way files are actually represented.

Answer (score 0):

It could be that you are missing a makefile in your src/ directory.

Answer (score 0):

dont put paths in the rules

```
 %.o: %.cpp
     g++ $(CC_FLAGS) $@ $<
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the main problem is you are not giving the proper path to the files you are trying to build. But also you missed some flags for `g++`. I think the following changes should work (not properly tested).

```
CPP_FILES = $(wildcard src/*.cpp)
OBJ_FILES = $(patsubst src/%.cpp,build/%.o,$(CPP_FILES))
CXXFLAGS = -Wall

all: prereqs lib/libphoto.a

lib/libphoto.a: $(OBJ_FILES)
    ar rcs $@ $^

build/%.o: src/%.cpp
    g++ -c $(CXXFLAGS) -o $@ $<

prereqs:
    mkdir -p lib
    mkdir -p build

.PHONY: prereqs 

clean:
    rm  $(OBJ_FILES) lib/libphoto.a
```